# Autoshrink on custom nav bar title

Tags: swift

I have a custom nav bar view so I can add multiple bar buttons to each side. Thus, I want to autoshrink the nav bar title rather than truncate it. I can't figure out how to do so with the following code I'm using.

```
navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 44))

navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor() // Sets bar to black

navBar.translucent = false

self.view.addSubview(navBar)

navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "A Pretty Long String") 

navBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 25)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call this function

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    println(self.view.frame.size)
    println(self.view.navBar.frame.size)
}
```

and in that function change a variable which you use for the font size in the NSFontAttributeName function

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the logic. How would I use a frame size as a font size?